# What JSON should i put in REST Client to test the given Schema

Tags: json, mongodb, api, rest, mongoose

I had been trying to insert a document from given schema but can't able to insert it through REST Client. pastie for code is given below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countries = require('../countries/countries.model');
var Employees = require('../Employees/Employees.model');

var countryModel = new countries();
var EmpModel = new Employees();

var City = new Schema({
    name: String,
    active: Boolean,
    countryId: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:countryModel},
    Employees: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: EmpModel}]
});
```

I had input various styles of JSON but none had succeeded

```
{
"name": "Delhi NCR",
"active": "true",
"countryId": country[0]._id,
Employees: [employees[1]._id]
}
```

---

```
 {
"name": "Delhi NCR",
"active": "true",
"countryId": "ObjectId(xxxxxxxxx)",
Employees: ["ObjectId(xxxxxxxxx)", "ObjectId(xxxxxxxxx)"]
}
```

---

```
  {
"name": "Delhi NCR",
"active": "true",
"countryId": "56dcccdddddddddaaaaaaaaa",
Employees: ["56dcccdddddddddaaaaaaaaa", "56dcccdddddddddaaaaaaaaa"]
}
```

But none of it work. What is the JSON which i should enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are referencing the models in your schema definition is not correct. The `ref` option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in your case you are using the actual model object instead of a string value with the model name:

```
var City = new Schema({
    name: String,
    active: Boolean,
    countryId: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: "countries"},
    Employees: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Employees"}]
});
```

Once you redefine the schema then you can pass in the document `_id`s from the `Employees` model as strings, since Mongoose will automatically cast those to ObjectIds under the hood.

```
"Employees": ["56dcccdddddddddaaaaaaaaa", "56dcccdddddddddaaaaaaaaa"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string for the active field instead of a boolean in your JSON.

```
 {
  "name": "Delhi NCR",
  "active": true,
  "countryId": ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4"),
   "Employees": [ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4"), ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4")]
 }
```

Comment: saving like this     {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d6be820d4590xxxxxxxx39"),
    "Employees" : [],
    "countryId" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}